# Why Teams API for web Apps crashes IOS Teams app?

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have an app published in the Teams App Store which uses task module and tabs.

On Task/Tab pages we use Teams API lib to work with media (camera/gallery). Camera and gallery API works fine if we limit users to only one image to pick.
On Android everything works great (doesn't matter how many media files you pick).
Strange things happen when we let IOS users to pick/make more than one image at a time.

There are two possible scenarios on IOS devices:

1. Teams App crashes.
2. Teams API returns attachments.length !== blobs.length.

I did some tests on different IOS Devices. Both have issues. I've updated the app to the latest and it got even worse (started to crash more often):

```
iPhone Xs (IOS 15.1).
iPhone 11 Pro Max (IOS 15.1).
```

Steps to reproduce blob issue:

1. Create an HTML page and load it into Task module.
2. Trigger `microsoftTeams.media.selectMedia` with maxMediaCount: 10.
3. Pick up to 10 small size images.
4. Save received attachments.length.
5. Request a blob for each attachment.
6. Calculate how many blobs and attachments you've got.

**Expected**: blobs.length === attachments.length.

**Result**: blobs.length !== attachments.length.

The issue described above appears randomly, sometimes you get expected values, sometimes you don't, sometimes it crashes even with small images.

How to crash IOS Teams App, Steps to reproduce:

1. Create an HTML page and load it into Task module.
2. Trigger `microsoftTeams.media.selectMedia` with maxMediaCount: 10.
3. Pick up to 10 big size images.

**Expected**: "Error 10000, Selected file is too big".

**Result**: Teams App crashes.

My code:

```
const MEDIA_MAX_FILES = 10;
const imageProp: microsoftTeams.media.ImageProps = {
    sources: [microsoftTeams.media.Source.Gallery],
    startMode: microsoftTeams.media.CameraStartMode.Photo,
    ink: false,
    cameraSwitcher: true,
    textSticker: true,
    enableFilter: true,
  };
  const mediaInput: microsoftTeams.media.MediaInputs = {
    mediaType: microsoftTeams.media.MediaType.Image,
    maxMediaCount: MEDIA_MAX_FILES,
    imageProps: imageProp
  };

  const attachementsList = [];
  const blobs = [];
  microsoftTeams.media.selectMedia(mediaInput,(error: microsoftTeams.SdkError,
                                               attachments: microsoftTeams.media.Media[]) => {
    if (error) { /* block is truncated */ return; }
    if (attachments) {
      attachementsList.push(...attachments);
      for (const attachment of attachments) {
        attachment.getMedia((attachmentError: SdkError,
                             blob: Blob) => {
          if (blob) {
            blobs.push(blob);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Teams App build versions. Dev Preview is turned on on both devices:

```
iPhone Xs: 3.20.77.2021202701/1121
iPhone 11 Max Pro: 3.20.77.2021202701/1121
```

Is this a bug ? Or am I doing something wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We tried to repro the issue at our end using iOS and it worked fine for us. It shows us `10000` error when the size limit exceeds. Teams App Build Version: `iPhone 12 : Version-3.19.0  ,  Build: 3.19.77.2021193101/1111`

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT We successfully reproduced the issue on iPhone 6s, IOS 15.2, Teams app version is 3.20.0. Please try to use this html code i've made for debugging https://github.com/skal1ozz/TeamsAppCrasher
Unfortunately I don't have access to iPhone 12 and can't confirm it's working fine on this mobile device.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Also can you please try to update the app to the latest one? It worked more stable for us as well on the older app versions.

Comment: Could you please follow this sample(https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-device-permissions/nodejs) and check if it helps you in any way. We tried to reproduce this issue using this sample with  `iPhone 12 : iOS 15.1.1 , Microsoft Teams Version-3.20.0 , Build: 3.20.77.2021202701/1121` and it worked for us.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT we've tried to run the app from the link you posted and seems like it can't compile out of the box, got:
    Failed to compile
    ./src/index.js 1:47
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:47)"

I'm fixing this to make tests. Will post info when it's fixed.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Ok so yeah i've managed compile the App and to repro the issue on your example application. Here's the thing, in your example app you don't actually do anything with the payload. The example app works only with preview data: src={"data:" + item.mimeType + ";base64," + item.preview}. But once you request a payload with "getMedia" it will crash the Teams App. You can try it by your own:

File "CaptureImage.rsx", between lines 51 and 52, just add this line: item.getMedia((error, blob) => { console.log(); });

Comment: We are able to repro the issue in iOS like you mentioned, the app is crashing. We have raised a bug for this and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update.

Comment: This is working fine now. The app is not crashing. Please do verify.